# How to drag and drop ImageView over another ImageView

Tags: android

I have 2 ImageViews inside the same RelativeLayout and I want to be able to drag and drop one of the ImageViews(small one) anywhere on top of the second ImageView(fills entire screen).
I'm still new to Android programming and I wanted to see some code on how to achieve this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@aci89

Drag and drop easy to use but its not convenient way for good programming, 
you are new in android so i suggest you not to do that

if you want to add imageview over imageview then use framelayout for that

[Link 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm)

and also refer android developer tutorial for more information   [Link 2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) [link 3](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Comment: Thanks @nil so what would you recommend as the best layout for drag and drop?

Comment: again you are going for drag and drop,@Aci89. every properties you can not set via drag and drop so try directly by xml codding. and another thing you must be keep it in mind that which layout you should use, it only depends on your needs and design requirements. you are beginner so try to follow: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html